# I am new in java coding I had certain code which is duplicating below the details

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

## service class details

```
public ViewRoleInfo viewRoles(String roleDescription,Authentication authentication) {
    logger.info(Utility.ENTERED + new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
    viewRoleInfo = new ArrayList<>();
    veiwRoleDetials = new ViewRoleInfo();
    viewAllServices = new ArrayList<>();
    viewAllRoles = new ArrayList<>();


    List<Jmrrole> jmrrole = roleRepo.findViewRoles(roleDescription);


            jmrrole.stream().forEach(viewRoles ->{

            viewAllServices.add(new ViewAllTransactions(viewRoles.getJmrtransactionm().getDescrption(),viewRoles.getAllowAuthorization(),viewRoles.getAllowInitiation(),viewRoles.getAllowView()));
            viewAllRoles.add(new ViewAllRoles( viewRoles.getJmrservicem().getDescription(),viewAllServices));

            viewRoleInfo.add(new ViewRoleInfo( viewRoles.getDescription(),viewRoles.getJmrdevicem().getNamdevice(),viewRoles.getCreatedby(),viewRoles.getDatcreated(),viewAllRoles));

            System.out.println(viewRoles.getDescription()+viewRoles.getJmrdevicem().getNamdevice()+viewRoles.getCreatedby()+viewRoles.getDatcreated()+viewAllRoles);
            veiwRoleDetials.setRoleDescription(viewRoles.getDescription());
            veiwRoleDetials.setChannel(viewRoles.getJmrdevicem().getNamdevice());
            veiwRoleDetials.setCreatedBy(viewRoles.getCreatedby());
            veiwRoleDetials.setCreatedOn(viewRoles.getDatcreated());



        });
        veiwRoleDetials.setViewAllRoles(viewAllRoles);

        return veiwRoleDetials;


}}
```

## Below is the json output that is comming while executing

```
http://path/path1/MCXcorpRole11
{
"errorStatus": false,
"errorMsgs": [],
"roleDescription": "MCXcorpRole11",
"channel": "Mobile Browser",
"createdBy": "superadmin",
"createdOn": "2017-04-17",
"viewAllRoles": [
{
"seriveName": "Transfer ",
"viewAllTransactions": [
{
"transactionName": "Own Accoount Transfer",
"allowAuthorization": "N",
"allowInitiation": "Y",
"allowView": "Y"
},
{
"transactionName": "Vendor Payments",
"allowAuthorization": "N",
"allowInitiation": "Y",
"allowView": "Y"
},
{
"transactionName": "Bulk Registration",
"allowAuthorization": "N",
"allowInitiation": "Y",
"allowView": "Y"
},
{
"transactionName": "Mobile payment",
"allowAuthorization": "Y",
"allowInitiation": "N",
"allowView": "N"
}
]
}
```

## But in DB we have mapping as mention below

```
"seriveName": "Transfer "
is only mapped with 
"transactionName": "Own Accoount Transfer"
```

## so I am expecting the output like this

```
"roleDescription": "MCXcorpRole11",
"channel": "Mobile Browser",
"createdBy": "superadmin",
"createdOn": "2017-04-17",
"viewAllRoles": [
{
"seriveName": "Transfer ",
"viewAllTransactions": [
{
"transactionName": "Own Accoount Transfer",
"allowAuthorization": "N",
"allowInitiation": "Y",
"allowView": "Y"
}]
```

## Can Someone figure it out where i did mistake here,Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I don't see you're referring the viewAllServices or attach viewAllServices to viewRoleDetails.

Comment: Thanks for response, Please clear me is am missing some thing here

Comment: viewAllServices.add(new ViewAllTransactions(viewRoles.getJmrtransactionm().getDescrption(),viewRoles.getAllowAuthorization(),viewRoles.getAllowInitiation(),viewRoles.getAllowView()));
            viewAllRoles.add(new ViewAllRoles( viewRoles.getJmrservicem().getDescription(),viewAllServices));    In viewRoles.getJmrtransactionm() how many records you will get? It looks like, you are adding one transaction to the viewAllServices and get incremented in the next iteration.  You need to look at your scenario and rewrite the above two lines.

Comment: In viewRoles.getJmrtransactionm() actually 4 rows there, Its would be greatful if you could find it out where is the mistake.As from past few days I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: I believe, some where your relationship or references are incorrect. I don't see any code issue. but issue in your POJO mapping properties or the db relationship